# Character Device Driver Read/Write in Linux

Tags: c, linux, module, char, driver

I've written a character device driver that, I believe, should work.

I want to test the read/write functions. On another stack overflow question, apparently this can be done by writing to the device file in /dev and echoing the output.

I don't understand how this works:

When I load up my device driver by allocating a major number and calling mknod to create the file, is the file "open"? If it isn't open, then reading/writing shouldn't work like that from the command line, or so I thought?

What state is the device driver in when it has been initialized in /proc/devices and a file created in /dev?

Does this initialization need to happen before attempting to open the device file in a c program?

These answer are extremely difficult to find online, and many resources are outdated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One good resource is [Linux device driver](https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/). A shorter and simpler explanation can be found [here](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.4/html/x579.html).

When you create a file driver, you will implement some functions among file operations (fops):

- `open`
- `close`
- `read`
- `write`
- `seek`
- ...

Not all function have to be implemented. If `write` is not implemented for instance, your device won't support writting.

> When I load up my device driver by allocating a major number and calling mknod to create the file, is the file "open"?

When the `/dev` file is created, your module is only *inited*. A function like `init_module` is called

When the file is removed, your module is *deinited*. A function like `module_cleanup` is called.

> What state is the device driver in when it has been initialized in /proc/devices and a file created in /dev?

In that case, the module is inited, the file are not open.

> If it isn't open, then reading/writing shouldn't work like that from the command line, or so I thought?

When you read a file from command line, the file is open, read then closed, as a user, you don't have to care to open/close file explicitly.

Things are different if you are a C programmer, in that case, you explicitly have to open, read, close the files.

You can check that adding traces in your kernel code (using `printk` to print some info to kernel console, reading it with `dmesg`) or using `strace` that will trace the system calls.

> Does this initialization need to happen before attempting to open the device file in a c program?

Let's resume:

- The first function called will be `module_init` before it's called, the file doesnot exist in `/dev`
- The last function called will be `module_cleanup` after it's called, the file doesnot exist in `/dev`
- between init and cleanup, you can call the different `open`, `close`, `read` and `write` function.
  Generally `read`/`write` are called between `open` and `close`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Great response.. I have one more question: If my driver specifically wants 8 byte (long) values as input, should I enforce that within the write function of the driver?

Comment: the third parameter of `device_read` and `device_write` is for that.

Comment: Upon experimenting, it seems the third parameter equals the size of the data passed in by the user, no? Is it not directly passed down by the write() unistd call's third parameter?

Comment: What is the best practice if the third parameter is less than 8 bytes?